# Analyzing all cells vs 3 samples

Tags: sampling, mean, biostatistics

I'm new to cross validated and even though I have a "decent" (at least for a biotechnologist) non-formal training (mostly self taught) in statistics I have problems with an issue.

In my lab we analyze pathology slides stained with several different markers. We run single-cell analysis for several variables.

I want to analyze the complete tumor slide, or at least the complete area of interest (sometimes we want to analyze just the center of the tumor, or the margin, etc.) But he wants to analyze 3 different smaller regions so we can have a mean and sd.  These are pilot projects, so often we don't get more samples to have a better sample.

Which approach is better?

EDIT: I use imaging software for to analyze the cells. We use a nuclear dye to "count" the cells. The software uses algorithms to find the perimeter of each nucleus and we assume number of cells = number of nucleus in the tissues we study. The images we have, are multilayered. Each layer corresponds to one marker. In general, our approach is to investigate many different markers/proteins/characteristics of the tissues. Each marker gives us an image by itself. We then analyze intensities of expression for each marker, overlap/co-expression of different markers. An expert pathologist then sets a threshold of positive vs negative for each marker. The software allows the pathologist to visually determine this threshold. After that, we are interested in the percentages for each different combination.

Example: If we analyze markers a, b, and c.

We want to know how many cells are positive for a, b and c (a+ b+ c+), how many are positive for a, positive for b, and NEGATIVE for c (a+ b+ c-), how many a+ b- c-, and so on.

Tissue samples are limited, so we often do not have "a good" n. My boss' approach is to instead of analyzing the complete region of interest (sometimes we are interested in the whole slide, sometimes just the tumor, sometimes, just a specific part of the tumor, etc), he prefers to analyze 3 or more very small areas within our regions of interest. He does that so we can get a mean with SD.

In my head... since each slide is a small sample of the tumor (or whatever tissue we are analyzing. Usually s thin slice of the whole tissue). Analyzing this sample as thoroughly as possible would be better.

I know we should probably consult a statistician or something, but unfortunately there's a lot of "politics" involved in doing so... at least in my institution. This is me trying to consult experts.

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: just to understand, you find the 'single cells' by some marker and then define some single-cell characteristic (eg nuclear morphology, surface stianing, etc?).  you have to be clear about what you look at. you could for instance derive characteristics for the marginal region (X amount of cells) and center (X amount of cells). this way you grasp the histological variation in your dataset. do you score manually or digital(ImageJ etc)? let us know!

Answer (score 1):

Given the extensive genetic and phenotypic heterogeneity among cells within tumors, I am increasingly skeptical of any reports that rely on a single determination from a tumor sample, absent evidence that a single determination is adequate. So multiple samples are best, and I would argue necessary when developing new markers. See [this paper](http://ascopubs.org/doi/abs/10.1200/jco.2008.18.7393) for discussion of why multiple measurements on a single tumor are part of best practice for developing biomarkers.

That said, there is no reason that the multiple regions analyzed have to be small. One could argue that you should analyze as much of the sample as possible so that you do not throw away useful information.

One solution here would to take the entire region of interest and break it into 3 or more sub-regions that cover the entire region of interest. Thoroughly analyze each of the sub-regions. Then you both have your measure of intra-tumor variability and complete coverage of your region of interest.

Comment: @ EdM Interesting input. I never considered taking different samples/slides of the same tumor. But it definitely seems reasonable. As I mentioned, sometimes samples are limited, but I think  often we can definitely do more than 1 section.
What would be your approach in selecting the sections of the tumor to use? One from the center, and 2 closer to the side edges? I'm guessing if we chose 3 consecutive serial sections, we wouldn't see a lot of this heterogeneity.

Comment: @jesusgarciab you want to sample the geographic heterogeneity, so as you suggest center and 2 near different edges would be a good choice; maybe even more than 3 samples, if possible, particularly if you don't yet know how heterogeneous your signals can be within a tumor. As you note there would only be small differences expected among consecutive serial sections, as they are only a few micrometers thick each and the serial sections would be sampling many of the same cells.